Connected rings and ideals
In what follows, a ring will denote a commutative ring with unity.
I was doing some problems from a Commutative Algebra class and I came across the following problem/idea. It is a common practice to characterize some ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ in terms of a property of the quotient ring $R/I$. We can summarize some of these characterizations in the following result:
Proposition. Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. Then:
1) $I$ is a prime ideal if and only if $R/I$ is an integral domain;
2) $I$ is a maximal ideal if and only if $R/I$ is a field;
3) $I$ is a radical ideal if and only if $R/I$ is reduced (i.e., has no non-trivial nilpotents).
The problem I was solving was about finding non-trivial ($\neq 0,1$) idempotents in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Although I solved the problem, I started thinking about rings with no non-trivial idempotents, which I discovered are called connected rings, due to the following beautiful result:
Proposition. A ring $R$ is connected if and only if the spectrum $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ with the Zariski topology is connected.
Then, the following question came to my mind:
Question. What types of ideals $I \subseteq R$ give rise to a connected quotient $R/I$?
So far, we know that $R/I$ is connected if and only if, given $\bar{x} \in R/I$,
$$ [ \:\: \bar{x}^2=\bar{x} \:\: \Longrightarrow \:\: \bar{x}=\bar{0} \:\: \text{or} \:\: \bar{x}=\bar{1} \:\: ] \Longleftrightarrow [ \:\: x(x-1)\in I \Longrightarrow \:\: x \in I \:\: \text{or} \:\: x-1\in I \:\: ], $$
which suggests the following definition:
Definition. A proper ideal $I \subseteq R$ is called connected (tentative name) if for a given element $x \in R$ such that $x(x-1) \in I$, we have $x \in I$ or $x-1 \in I$.
My (soft) questions are the following: Is there an existing name for these types of ideals? What properties do these ideals have (apart from the obvious, such as any prime ideal being of this type)? Is there a relation between these ideals and radical ideals?
Thank you in advance!

Recall that the zero ring is not connected (see here). So this is missing in your definition. We need $I \neq R$. (Just as for prime ideals.)

The term "connected ideal" is used in the case of topological rings and semigroups, here connected more directly refers to the given tolology. So maybe we need a different name.

The paper J-spaces and C-normal spaces: An algebraic perspective uses "Z-connected" for a closely related notion.

Thank you, @MartinBrandenburg, for your comments! I will update the definition in the post to adress the issue with the zero ring, and I will take a look at the paper you mentioned.

It's a very natural idea, one which I don't recall seeing a name in print for before today.
"Connected ideal" is certainly a natural name for it as you noted. But also one might consider that since connectedness of $R/I$ amounts to direct indecomposability of the module $(R/I)_R$, one might logically call it "co-indecomposability." Indeed when searching I found Bezhanishvili, G., P. J. Morandi, and B. Olberding. "Pierce sheaves and commutative idempotent generated algebras." Fund. Math 240.2 (2018): 105-136. which has on page 17

By Proposition 3.2 and Theorem 5.1, each stalk of $A$ is of the form $R/I$, where $I$ is a coindecomposable ideal of R (meaning that $I$ is a proper ideal and $R/I$ is an indecomposable ring).

By searching for the phrase "$R/I$ is connected" I found McAdam, Stephen, and Richard G. Swan. "Unique comaximal factorization." Journal of Algebra 276.1 (2004): 180-192, where they define pseudo-irreducible elements of a commutative ring, and remark in Lemma 3.1 that $b$ is pseudo-irreducible iff $R/(b)$ is a connected ring.  What you are looking at is a sort of ideal theoretic generalization of 'pseudo irreducible element.'  Indeed the authors go on in section 5 of the paper to consider a pseudo-irreducible ideal $I$ meaning $R/I$ is connected.

As for implicational relationships between radical and connected ideals, there is no containment. $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is reduced but not connected, meaning the zero ideal is radical but not connected.  In any local ring whose maximal ideal squares to zero, you have a ring where the zero ideal is connected but is not radical.  I think in general there is not much to say about the relationship.
OTOH one thing that springs to mind regarding idempotents and rings without nonzero nilpotents is this:

In a reduced ring (a ring without nonzero nilpotent elements) every idempotent is central.

The converse is not true, as any local ring with nonzero nilpotent maximal ideal demonstrates.  Since you are interested in commutative rings, this is probably of limited use to you.
